# Why won't Ubuntu's Python let me load a file?

Tags: file, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use a Windows 10 laptop.

I downloaded a dataset for learning purposes but every time I get this when I try to load the file on Ubuntu:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: (Not showing this part bc it contains my name, but it's the path to the file in question)

The file I am trying to load has the exact path that I put in. My code looks like this:
data = list(parse_data(r"C:(stuff about my windows user)\theFile.json"))

It works on the Python in Windows command prompt but not on Ubuntu, which is specifically what I'd like to use. Any reason why Ubuntu can't access it but Windows can? What should I do?

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm new to this. Thanks

Comment: When you run this in Ubuntu you need to use the path in Ubuntu's file system.

Comment: use forward slashes, not backslashes, for paths. If you want platform independence, build paths from `os.path` or `pathlib`.

Comment: Considering that this question is specifically about file paths, its odd that you don't post a path (with your account name changed). It appears that you are using Windows style paths on linux. And that means _The file I am trying to load has the exact path that I put in._ is not correct. If we see, we may be able to fix.

Comment: linux uses `/` as a sperator but you can use pathlib to get os independent paths, also as written in [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq), it's in `/mnt/c/` etc not `c:\\`

Comment: @Sobhan thank you so much! that was exactly the issue. it works now. much appreciated!